# Wordpress port removal gives 301 error

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, port

I have a wordpress website. In the website url section it automatically adds the port :80 at the end. It also adds the same port to every link on the website and to permalinks. This is a big issue for my employer because it is bad for SEO supposedly. Howevery, when I try to change the 'example.com:80' to just 'example.com' the website becomes unreachable with 301 error coming up. However, I am still able to log into wordpress admin section. So, is there a way to either remove ports from permalinks manually somewhere or if there is a way to change the website url so that it does not have the port in it.

http://example.com:80/sample-post/ - this is the example of the permalink

http://example.com/sample-post/ - this is what is desirable

Thank you

Comment: I dont have any code. I just changed the port and it all went bad. I dont even know where to start

Comment: Why tagged the question with htaccess then ?:)

Answer (score 2):

In your wordpress settings, change the site url and wp url to your domain without :80. Port 80 is the default http port and so that is what your webserver listens on anyway (unless explicitly set up otherwise).

**Update**

Not sure about your exact setup, but here is what you should add to your `.htaccess` to redirect all requests to :80 explicitly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org:80/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Change `example.org` to your domain.

Comment: I did that but the website becomes unavailable with 301 error.

Comment: @MikhailKashtaev Odd. not sure about your exact setup, so updated answer to include a `.htaccess` redirect rule to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Disable Canonical URL Redirection](http://txfx.net/files/wordpress/disable-canonical-redirects.phps)

Drop the plugin into your wp-content/plugins directory and we will then need to activate it outside the admin area by fixing the database directly (I used Sequel Pro). Here’s how:

1. Locate the wp_options table
2. Set active_plugins to a:1:{i:0;s:31:"disable-canonical-redirects.php";}
3. Change the values of siteurl and home to / (might not be strictly necessary)
   http://localhost:8080/ should now work correctly.

Just remember to disable/remove the plugin in production environment. The SQL values you just fudged would be correctly resaved once you have access to the admin section.